# How to estimate the computational time of a program

Tags: grid, system, computation-theory

I am doing a project where I need to estimate the computational time of running a program for a given input for a specific configuration of a mobile device.

More precisely, suppose I have a program where out of m instructions n instructions can be executed in parallel. Suppose my computer has the following configurations:

processor: 2.5GHz core i 5
RAM: 4GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Cache: 2MB

Based on the above configuration or some additional information (if required) is there any equation whereby i can tell that how much time it might require to run my program?

Second question: suppose I know that for executing my program in the above mentioned configuration I need t seconds. Based on that can I estimate how much time it might take for a device which has different configuration say 2 GHz core i5 with 3GB DDR3 ram and 1 MB cache?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Such a question is pretty much impossible to answer. There are far more variables than just number of instructions (running serially or in parallel). For instance, is virtual memory in play? If so, you never know when your program is going to have one of its pages ejected. And when your program will need that page again. Worst case scenario your pages start thrashing and your execution time goes all to hell.

After virtual memory you need to consider how many of your variables have been cached and in what level of cache they may exist. If you have multiple cores and a multi-threaded application you have to deal with the overhead of cache coherency protocols.

Both virtual memory operations and data retrieval are far, *far* slower than instruction execution. Many orders of magnitude slower.

Even if you take all of that out of the picture (leaving you with a completely worthless execution time value) and just calculate the amount of time it takes to execute the instructions you open up a whole new can of worms. First you'd need to know the CPI (cycles per instruction) of your processor.

The take-away here is that trying to predict execution time just on number of instructions is all but impossible. The same is true for the second question.

**Edited to add**

I forgot about Ahmdal's law. If you want a purely theoretical approach to this. You might want to look into this a little bit. There's a pretty simple equation about how much speed up you can get by adding more parallel resources.  [Ahmdal's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Can it possible to do any statistical analysis from some sample programs of different sizes and from there provide a conclusion of running time of any give program?

Comment: I actually already checked Ahmdal's law and it has shown some relation between time and number of cores and the number of instructions executed in parallel. But I believe just based on the number of cores we cannot estimate the time accurately

Comment: That's probably the only way to do it. You'd want a high sample size. You'd probably also want to kill as many other running processes as you can to get a more accurate time.

Comment: I was also looking for some papers related to my project but unfortunately so far couldnt find something related except the Ahmdal's law. I would be thankful if you recommend me something which I can read for gathering some idea to proceed my project

Comment: I don't know of any specific papers either. I would recommend "Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach" by John L. Hennessy and David A. Patterson. Section 1.6 through 1.10 talk about this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look on that.